# Automatically switch channel mode when headphones are plugged in?

Tags: alsa, soundcard

I have an ASUS Xonar DGX soundcard. I was able to get audio playing out-of-the-box, however I am having issues with audio switching when headphones are plugged into the front panel.

I have plugged the "HD Audio" connector from my case directly into the soundcard. Previously, it was plugged into the motherboard and audio switching worked correctly, but I want to use the soundcard for the front panel audio.

I always have speakers plugged into the 3.5mm jack on the soundcard and sometimes have headphones plugged into the front panel 3.5mm jack.

If I open alsamixer, then I can toggle the "Analog Output" channel between:

- "Stereo Headphones"
- "Stereo Headphones FP"
- "Multichannel"

[image]

- If I select "Stereo Headphones", then audio plays from the speakers.
- If I select "Multichannel", then audio plays from the speakers but much louder.
- If I select "Stereo Headphones FP", then audio plays from the headphones plugged into the front panel 3.5mm.

**What I would like to achieve is when I plug headphones into the front panel, the audio is automatically switched to there. When I unplug the headphones, audio should be automatically switched back to the speakers.**

I would also like to maintain separate volume levels for the two 3.5mm jacks.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

According to alsamixer I have 3 soundcards, but I only want to use [2] Xonar DGX.

---

**Update**

Test suggested below...

```bsh
$ cat /proc/asound/card1/oxygen > before.txt 

# Plugs in headphones

$ cat /proc/asound/card1/oxygen > after.txt 

$ diff before.txt after.txt 
12c12
< a0: 00 00 00 00 3f 00 f8 01 e0 01 00 00 00 00 00 00
---
> a0: 00 00 00 00 3f 00 e8 01 e0 01 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Comment: HP detection is currently not supported by the DG driver. Does the seventh value in the `a0:` line in `/proc/asound/card2/oxygen` change when you (un)plug the headphones?

Comment: @CL Added the test to answer